# missing some value while inserting csv into ms access on window 7

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, csv, windows-7, visual-studio-2005

[image]

While inserting this comma seperated csv file into ms access on Window 7, a row for **P0064** is with its blank value under Barcode column in ms access.

[image]

Coding is

```
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO [MS Access;Database=" & g_Database & "].[" & strTable & "] " & _
                    "(RefNo," & TP_Barcode & "," & TP_ScanDate & ") " & _
                    "SELECT '" & strRefNo & "'," & TP_Barcode & ", ScanDate " & "FROM [Text;DATABASE=" & _
                    strImportFilePath & "\].[" & strModule & ".CSV]"

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, m_DBConn)
        Return (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1)
```

It works in window xp. What is my missing portion for window 7 ?

Thank you.

---

For window 7, my working code is

```
    '********
    'OLEDB
    '********
    'Datatable from CSV
    Dim file As String = "Picking.csv"
    Dim path As String = g_CSVPath
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        If IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(path, file)) Then
            Dim ConStr As String = _
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
            path & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited(,)"""
            Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr)
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from " & _
            file, conn)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    'Insert data
    Dim r, c As Integer
    Dim sBarcode, sDate As String
    For r = 1 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

        sBarcode = dt.Rows(r)(0)
        sDate = dt.Rows(r)(1)

        Dim strSQL As String
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO strTable (TP_Barcode , TP_ScanDate ) VALUES ('" & sBarcode & "', '" & sDate & "')"

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, m_DBConn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
```

It also **works** like this data

[image]

But **doesn't work** like this data - Barcode and W0002 are read as Null. :(

### [image]

Here for inserting, actually i like to try batch inserting. i tried this code but it fails - **no record insert**

```
'Insert Data from DataTable into Access database  
    Using cnn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False")  
        Dim cmdSelect As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select TP_Barcode , TP_ScanDate From strTable ")  
        cmdSelect.Connection = cnn  
        Dim ad As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSelect)  
        Dim cmdBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(ad)  
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand()  
        cmd.Connection = cnn  
        ad.InsertCommand = cmd  
        ad.Update(dt)  
    End Using
```

May I know what my missing is ?

Thank you.

Comment: What message error occur ?

Comment: sorry @GoroundoVipa. i already edit my post. there is no error. Just its blank value.

Comment: Is TP_Barcode a number field or a text field?

Comment: @AVG, it's a text field.

Comment: Two suggestions:
In Access, press shift + F2 to open the zoom box while on the 'blank' Barcode. This will open the zoom box. Should there happen to be a leading CrLf the field would appear blank, where it actually is not.
Instead of doing an insert, put the data into a datatable and debug.print each field/record. This will help you determine the source of the problem.

Comment: @AVG, from a datatable, P0064 is shown. can we say that my coding only works for window xp?

Comment: @AVG, during loading csv data into a datatable - if HDR=No, P0064 is shown. But if HDR=Yes, it's null value. is it strange in window 7 ?

Comment: @soclose I hink that is has to do with the provider in you connection. When HDR=No it sees the header as data, and therefore, all text. Just a guess here, but I think, since the first row is a number, that column is being considered a number column, when there is text in it, it is being discarded. From what I remember (going way back) it should be looking at about 25 rows (IIRC there is a registry setting) to determine field type, and it seems that for some reason it is not. I suggest researching whatever provider you are using and posting your connection string. Someone my spot something.